# Add an Action Button based on column value using DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a text file that contains data in json format. The datas are displayed in the [table] (http://live.datatables.net/zuhojida/1/edit). Its got 3 columns, Alert, Ack, and Action.

This is my datatable code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshMaintTable = $('#maint-table').dataTable( {
            "bInfo": false,
            "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/maint_json.txt',
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "maint_alert" },
                { "mData": "maint_ack" },
                { "mData": "maint_action" },
            ],
        } );
        setInterval (function() {
            refreshMaintTable.fnDraw();
        }, 50000);
    } );
</script>
```

I want to know if dataTable can first check the value in the Ack column and if value is = 0 (this means that the alert has not yet been acknowledged), then it should display a button one can click on to acknowledge the alert. That button will change the value from 0 to 1.

Is this something DataTables can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var addButton = function(){
             $('#maint-table tr td').each(function(){

            if($(this).index() == 1 && $(this).html() == "0")
             {
               $(this).html($('<input type="button" value="ACK" onclick="$(this).parent().html(1);">'));
              }
             });
           }

        var refreshMaintTable = $('#maint-table').dataTable( {
            "bInfo": false,
            "sAjaxSource": 'ajax/maint_json.txt',
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "maint_alert" },
                { "mData": "maint_ack" },
                { "mData": "maint_action" },
            ],
            "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
               // call add button on page load 
          addButton();
            }
        } );


        setInterval (function() {
            refreshMaintTable.fnDraw();
            addButton();
        }, 50000);
    } );
```

**[Demo](http://live.datatables.net/zuhojida/6/edit)**

Comment: wahooo, this is great. I have looked at the demo and it looks cool. Just a question, when one clicks on Ack and refreshes the page, will the ack button appear again?

Comment: yes, as you can see we are calling `addButton();` inside setInterval again after redrawing datatable.

Comment: Just one more question, if the column Ack was on the last column, where in the code will I reference it?

Comment: You can call function on onclick of ACK button, see this http://live.datatables.net/zuhojida/7/edit

Comment: In if condition `$(this).index() == 1`, 1 refer to 2nd column. index are 0 based so 0=first col, 1= 2nd col and 2=3rd col and so on .. so you need to change this `$(this).index() == (column number - 1)`

Comment: cool, thanks so much. just to conclude, will I have to define this as a separate function in addition to my code above?

Comment: You need to copy `addButton` (please change table id to maint-table) and call addButton inside your setInterval and also after setInterval function. See updated answer

Comment: hmm strange, doing it as you have updated does not display the ACK button

Comment: I got the problem, as you are calling ajax for datatable, so you need to wait till ajax complete and then call addButton fuction. To do this you need to add `"fnDrawCallback"` in your datatable parameter and inside this call `addButton();` see [this](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/6576/datatables-table-loads-twice-first-time-without-table-data/p1) for fnDrawCallback

Comment: see updated answer, you need to move `addButton` function on the top as function should be define before it get called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59349/discussion-between-bhushan-kawadkar-and-chelseawillrecover).

Comment: you free for a chat now?