# Try to show table with action buttons - laravel 5.3 and dataTables.min.js

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables

I am new to laravel 5.3 and I am learning but I have a Problem which I can't solve maybe someone can help me. I want to show a Table (about) with some action buttons. When I visit the index.blade I get a exception in my logs and didn't see the table.

No table:
[image: No table]

With the develop tool from Chrome I get a 500 status.

First The Stack Trace

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function getForDataTable() on null in /var/www/html/heincloud/app/Http/Controllers/Backend/About/AboutTableController.php:26
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Backend\About\AboutTableController->__invoke(Object(App\Http\Requests\Backend\About\ManageAboutRequest))
#1 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9584): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9611): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('__invoke', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8665): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\Backend\About\AboutTableController), '__invoke')
#4 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8646): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#5 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8355): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/heincloud/app/Http/Middleware/SessionTimeout.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): App\Http\Middleware\SessionTimeout->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /var/www/html/heincloud/app/Http/Middleware/RouteNeedsPermission.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): App\Http\Middleware\RouteNeedsPermission->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'view-backend')
#12 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/heincloud/app/Http/Middleware/LocaleMiddleware.php(57): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10177): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(3312): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13749): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12155): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13495): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13432): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10054): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8356): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#39 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8347): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8338): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2575): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(3374): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10069): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /var/www/html/heincloud/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(10054): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2519): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 /var/www/html/heincloud/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2503): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /var/www/html/heincloud/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 {main}
```

index.blade -> script

```
@section('after-scripts')
    {{ Html::script("js/backend/plugin/datatables/jquery.") }}
    {{ Html::script("js/backend/plugin/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js") }}

 <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#about-table").DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ route("admin.about.get") }}',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {status: 1, trashed: false}
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'id', name: '{{config('access.about_table')}}.id'},
                    {data: 'title', name: '{{config('access.about_table')}}.title', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()},
                    {data: 'content', name: '{{config('access.about_table')}}.content', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()},
                    {data: 'user_id', name: '{{config('access.about_table')}}.user_id'},
                    {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', searchable: false, sortable: false}
                ],
                order: [[0, "asc"]],
                searchDelay: 500
      });
    });
  </script>
@stop
```

AboutModel

```
<?php

namespace App\Aboutpages;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Aboutpages\Traits\AboutAttribute;   
use Auth;

class About extends Model
{
    use AboutAttribute;

    protected $table = "about";
    public $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'user_id'];



    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->table = config('access.about_table');
    }



    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $model->user_id = Auth::id();
                $model->user_id = Auth::id();
            }
        });

        static::updating(function($model) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                $model->user_id = Auth::id();
            }
        });
    }  
}
```

ManageAboutRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Backend\About;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

/**
 * Class ManageAboutRequest.
 */
class ManageAboutRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return access()->allow('manage-about');
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

AboutRepository

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Backend\About;

use App\Aboutpages\About;
use App\Repositories\Repository;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * Class AboutRepository.
 */
class AboutRepository extends Repository
{
    /**
     * Associated Repository Model.
     */
    const MODEL = About::class;


    /**
     * @param string $order_by
     * @param string $sort
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getForDataTable($order_by = 'sort', $sort = 'asc')
    {
        return $this->query()

            ->orderBy($order_by, $sort)
            ->select([
                config('access.about_table').'.id',
                config('access.about_table').'.title',
                config('access.about_table').'.content',
                config('access.about_table').'.user_id',
                config('access.about_table').'.sort',
        ]);
    }
}
```

AboutTableController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend\About;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables;
use App\Repositories\Backend\About\About\AboutRepository;
use App\Http\Requests\Backend\About\ManageAboutRequest;

/**
 * Class AboutTableController.
 */
class AboutTableController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var AboutRepository
     */
    protected $about;
    /**
     * @param ManageAboutRequest $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke(ManageUserRequest $request)
    {
        return Datatables::of($this->about->getForDataTable($request->get('status'), $request->get('trashed')))
            ->addColumn('actions', function ($about) {
                return $about->action_buttons;
            })
            ->withTrashed()
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Haves no one a idea or can show me a easier way to add action buttons?

Comment: DId you checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305020/add-an-action-button-based-on-column-value-using-datatable#answers-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours of debugging i could find the mistake :D

I forgott to get the Request from the __Construct function in the AboutTableController. Without that  $this->about in line 26 returns null. After that and a few modifications it worked :)

```
public function __construct(AboutRepository $abouts)
{
    $this->abouts = $abouts;
}
```